# How to prevent GXT Dialog from closing on failed validation

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a simple GXT dialog window with 2 buttons, "OK" and "Cancel". When the OK button is pressed I validate that fields are not empty and I want to prevent the dialog window from been closed but I haven't been able to figure out how. Here's what I have

```
super.getButtonById(Dialog.OK).addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {
            if(netScanName.getValue() == null) {
                Util.alert("All fields are required!");
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

The event properly fires because i get my window alert but then the dialog continues to close any way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using GXT 3.0.x?

Using GXT 3.0.x I would solve your request by setting

```
dialog.setHideOnButtonClick(false);
```

To manage the closing of the dialogbox use this code:

```
dialog.getButtonById(PredefinedButton.OK.name()).addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    if (netScanName.getValue() == null) {
      Util.alert("All fields are required!");
    } else {
      dialog.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Don't know if this code will work with earlier versons of GXT.

Comment: I'm using GXT version 2.2 (unfortunately) but yes that's exactly that approach that I had to take to get it to behave the way that I wanted it to. Thanks!